# Let A and B be sets. Prove that A = B iff the power set of A is equal to the power set of B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am an undergraduate student. Please tell me if my proof is correct. Thanks!

**Let A and B be sets. Prove that A = B iff the power set of A is equal to the power set of B.**

Assume that A and B are any sets. If A = B, then every element of A is in B, and vice versa. Then the power sets are equal by definition.

Conversely, if the power sets of A and B are equal, we need to prove that A = B.
If A ≠ B. The power sets of A and B would not be equal, but they are equal, what is a contradiction. Therefore A = B. Q.E.D.

Comment: You need to say quite a bit more in both directions. If $A=B$, how do you know that $\wp(A)=\wp(B)$? I would simply show that if $S\in\wp(A)$, then $S\in\wp(B)$, and vice versa, thereby showing that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)\subseteq\wp(A)$ and hence that $\wp(A)=\wp(B)$. Similarly, if $A\ne B$, how do you know that $\wp(A)\ne\wp(B)$? You need to show why this is the case, which is most easily done by exhibiting a set that is in only of $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(B)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your comment! I am studying it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going forward is obvious.

Going backward, assume that the power sets are equal. Take $E \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ and take $x \in E$. Then $x \in B$. But $E \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, so $x \in A$. Hence, $A\subseteq B$.

Now, repeat the other way.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: Arkamis, or just note that $A\in\mathcal P(A)=\mathcal P(B)$ and therefore $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

No, your proof is not good. You're not explaining why $\mathcal P(A)\neq\mathcal P(B)$, you're just saying that different sets have different power sets, which is exactly what you should be proving.

Instead, let me give you a hint:
Note that if $\mathcal P(A)=\mathcal P(B)$, then you can prove $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am working on the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Something fishy has happened. Have you proved that, if $A \neq B$, they're power sets aren't equal? This is the converse of the statement that "If $A = B$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(B)$", which is not equivalent to what you want to prove.

I would think you could recover the original sets $A$ and $B$ by the singletons in their respective power sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May you explain more the last part of your answer?

Comment: @Beginner Sure, I mean that the power set of $A$ contains a bunch of singleton sets - one for each element of $A$. If you were to take the union of all those sets containing one element, you would arrive at the set $A$.